# inputting data from csv to sql tables in db2, via pentaho

Tags: db2, pentaho

rather new to the field.

could somebody please explain me the process to import data from a csv into sql tables built in db2 (i have no other options than using db2), using pentaho? would like to avoid the pain of inputting manually...

I see in pentaho that I'm asked for the connection where I want my data to land, but don't know how to figure out that address. [the screen in pentaho where i'm asked for connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNwMT.png)

thanks guys

Comment: You didn't provide any information about your Db2 server. Either you installed it and then should have information or you need to talk with the admins to get it from them.

Answer (score 0):

First off you beed to configure the connection to the DB, this is done with the connection wizard, in the following screen.

[image]

With this done, tested and ok, any step that requires a DB connection will have this connection available as option, from there you can use steps such as 'Table output', 'InsertUpdate' and so on.